# Htaccess rewriteRule if none of the above conditions match

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess and I am trying to rewrite all urls which would not match any of the rules.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# —————— rule1 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/learn/(why|about)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ./index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]

# —————— rule2 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/profile/edit$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=profile [L,QSA]

# —————— rule3 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/users/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ./index.php?page=user&userUrl=$2 [L,QSA]
```

What I would like is something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404 [L,QSA]
```

but it does not seem to work. Any way to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last catch-all rule would be like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# —————— rule1 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/learn/(why|about)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]

# —————— rule2 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/profile/edit$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=profile [L,QSA]

# —————— rule3 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/users/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=user&userUrl=$2 [L,QSA]

# —————— rule4 ——————
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php?page=404 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems it does redirect 127.0.0.1/ as well unfortunately (nothing after localhost in the url). Anything I can do about that?

Comment: localhost/folder_I_work_on/ which before the new condition would go to localhost/folder_I_work_on/index.php

Comment: `localhost/folder_I_work_on/` will be correctly routed to `localhost/folder_I_work_on/index.php` because last rule is for not-found file/directory only.

Comment: adding !-d condition on top of !-f does the trick. Thanks for the edit. What -f and -d options do?

Comment: `-f` checks if current request is for a real file and `-d` checks if current request is for a real directory.